# Customizing web.config for ASP.NET 5 (vNext) deployments

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using kpm pack to generate my deployment, which I deploy to Azure via ftp.  I need to be able to serve static json files, so I need to add the following to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="text/html" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

The problem is that kpm pack generates the web.config, so the only way to accomplish this is to  add the config section to the web.config after it's been generated.  Since I'm doing automated deployments via ci, this would require a bit of effort.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you saying your project has a `web.config` file, and `kpm pack` is overwriting it? Or it's ignored?

Comment: I do not have my own web.config.  I did try to put my one in wwwroot and kpm pack did overwrite it.

Comment: Got it. I asked one of the engineers on the ASP.NET team to take a look at this.

Comment: Please check out Wei's latest update to his answer - there was a bug in `kpm pack` that we have fixed for the next preview release. Thanks again for the report!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your configurations to the source of web.config, instead of the target.

If you don't have a web.config in root of the project being packed, please create one. Then add your static content configurations to [project_root]/web.config.

"kpm pack" will preserve all configurations in [project_root]/web.config, add some information needed by IIS, and then write it to wwwroot/web.config.

**Important Update:**

A change was introduced in "kpm pack": https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/pull/972

Please move your web.config from project root to the source of wwwroot.

The source of wwwroot folder can be specified with 'webroot' in project.json (https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#webroot).
You can also specify it with '--wwwroot' option of "kpm pack".

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I think having the web.config in wwwroot is much more intuitive.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I am on kpm version `1.0.0-beta1-10662` - does this version include the code to use the source `web.config` in `wwwroot`? If the version is too old, how do I update `kpm` to the latest version?

Comment: Try "kvm upgrade". If you don't have kvm, please install it by following instructions at [aspnet/Home](https://github.com/aspnet/Home).

Comment: what about console apps?

Comment: This question is not applicable to console apps because a console app doesn't need web.config nor wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core you may be able to avoid `web.config` altogether by configuring the static file middleware options ([`StaticFileOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFile/blob/d16a73cc05d842390768f78134c1eeb794215fae/src/Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles/StaticFileOptions.cs)) in code, providing a custom [`FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/d16a73cc05d842390768f78134c1eeb794215fae/src/Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs) as its `ContentTypeProvider`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    ...
    services.AddInstance<IContentTypeProvider>(
        new FileExtensionConentTypeProvider(
            new Dictionary<string, string>(
                // Start with the base mappings
                new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().Mappings,
                // Extend the base dictionary with your custom mappings
                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
                    { ".json", "text/html" }
                }
            )
        );
    ...
}

public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app, 
    IContentTypeProvider contentTypeProvider)
{
    ...
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
        ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```